# Ambiguity with multinomial logit models

Tags: multinomial-distribution, logit, log-linear

I have always thought that, when dealing with multinomial logistic regression, the idea was to linearly model the "logistic" functions of the probability densities of the different response categories (as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_set_of_independent_binary_regressions)). I put quotation marks around "logistic" since we do not use the real logistic functions, $\log\left(\frac{\pi_j(x)}{1-\pi_j(x)}\right)$, but with denominator equal to the density of a certain "pivot" category.

I then discovered the extension to a log-linear model, where the logarithms of the probability distributions, $\log(\pi_j(x))$, are directly modeled, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_log-linear_model). At the end of the day, it is still very similar to the previous assumption.

However, I had problems when I discovered the existence of this alternative formulation, which is explained in the `R` package `mlogit`'s [vignette (pdf)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf). Basically, every $\log(\pi_j(x))$ is modeled with $\alpha_j+\bar{\beta}\cdot\bar{x}$, where $\alpha_j$ is an intercept which is characteristic of every response category, and the vector of linear coefficients, $\bar{\beta}$, is the same for every category.

My question is not maybe a real question, but why this ambiguity?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an acknowledgment that this notation is misleading in the documentation of the `mlogit` package ([vignette (pdf)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf)). Page 8, *1.2 Model description:*

> while working with multinomial logit models, one has to consider three
>   kinds of variables:
>
> - alternative specific variables $x_{ij}$ with a generic coefficient $\beta$,
> - individual specific variables $z_i$ with an alternative specific    coefficients $\gamma_j$,
> - alternative specfic variables $w_{ij}$ with an alternative    specific coefficient $\delta_j$
>
> The satisfaction index for the alternative $j$ is then :
>
> $V_{ij}=\alpha_j+\beta x_{ij}+\gamma_j z_i+\delta_j w_{ij}$
>
> [...]
>
> A model with only individual specific variables is sometimes
>   called a *multinomial logit model*, one with only alternative
>   specific variables a *conditional logit model* and one with both kind
>   of variables a *mixed logit model*. This is seriously misleading :
>   *conditional logit model* is also a logit model for longitudinal data in the statistical literature and *mixed logit* is one of the names of
>   a logit model with random parameters. Therefore, in what follow, we'll
>   use the name *multinomial logit model* for the model we've just
>   described whatever the nature of the explanatory variables included in
>   the model.

I got a shiver down my spine when I read the last sentence.